# Generate two random numbers whose square sum ==1

Tags: python, numpy, random, geometry

Hi I would like to generate two random numbers so that the sum of their squares is equal to 1.

I have written this code. The sum of their square may not be perfectly equal to 1 but it should be near like 0.999. I also used `if(math.isclose(abs(gene_value_1)**2 + abs(gene_value_2)**2, 1))` but it doesn't work.

```
gene_value_1 = random.uniform(0, 1)
gene_value_2 = random.uniform(0, 1)
if(abs(gene_value_1)**2 + abs(gene_value_2)**2) == 1:
    print(added)
```

I want to generate two random numbers where the sum of their squares is nearly equal to 1.

Comment: How about `cos(angle)` and `sin(angle)` for a randomly chosen angle in `[-pi, pi]`?

Comment: Your problem statement is inconsistent.  If you have a condition that their square-sum is 1.0, then you do not have two random numbers: you have one random number, and a second derived from the first.  Are you trying to take random shots, and discover whether you've hit *close* to the unit circle?

Comment: Take 1 random number between 0 and 1, square it, subtract the square value from 1 and find the square root of that... you'll be lucky to generate two random numbers and hope their squares add up to 1

Comment: See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePointPicking.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your requirement is not really for two distinct numbers. It's for a single pair of numbers whose squared sum equals one.

If `x**2 + y**2 = 1`, then `y` is determined entirely by `x`: `y = sqrt(1 - x**2)`:

```
gene_value_1 = random.uniform(0, 1)
gene_value_2 = math.sqrt(1.0 - gene_value_1**2)
```

As mentioned in the comments both to the question and this answer, the distribution obtained in this manner is non-uniform with respect to the two numbers. Since `gene_value_1` and `gene_value_2` would describe a unit circle in Cartesian space in the uniform case, you can do

```
angle = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
gene_value_1 = math.cos(angle)
gene_value_2 = math.sin(angle)
```

Comment: While this satisfies the problem as requested, it's worth noting the resulting distribution is asymmetrical between x and y.  gene_value_2 will be greater than gene_value_1 most of the time (1/sqrt(2) ~ 0.71)

Comment: The polar method suggested in the comments above by @MarkDickinson is better. It generates x,y points uniformly distributed on the unit circle, where this method does not.

Comment: Both of the above comments mention a fair point, I think this should be included in the answer as a note.

Comment: @kmario. Added an additional addendum.

Comment: Looks good now  thanks for updating! The reason I suggested is that not everyone reads the comments section, particularly when the answer is accepted by OP.  + 1

Answer (score 2):

I give full credit to [Mark Dickinson's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047264/generate-two-random-numbers-whose-squre-sum-1#comment98736292_56047264) of using trigonometry for generating two random numbers whose squares sum to 1. This is one of the most important trigonometric identities and is sometimes termed as **Pythagorean formula for sines and cosines**

> sine^2 (theta) + cos^2(theta) = 1

Thus, we sample `theta` randomly in the interval `[-pi, pi]` and take the `sine` and `cosine` of it. This gives us two numbers which when squared independently and then summed would be equal to 1.

So, the implementation would look something like:

```
def squared_unity():
    r = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi)
    r1, r2 = np.cos(r), np.sin(r)
    # sanity check
    sq_sum = np.sum(np.square([r1, r2]))
    print("the two random numbers are: {}, {}".format(round(r1, 4), round(r2, 4)))
    print("sum of the squares of them is: {}".format(round(sq_sum, 4)))
```

---

```
In [172]: for i in range(10): 
     ...:     squared_unity() 

the two random numbers are: -0.4232, 0.906
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: -0.6432, 0.7657
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: -0.9854, 0.1701
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: 0.6192, -0.7852
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: 0.613, 0.7901
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: 0.3289, -0.9444
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: -0.6289, -0.7775
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: 0.5851, 0.811
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: -0.9515, 0.3076
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
the two random numbers are: 0.992, -0.1258
sum of the squares of them is: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> generate two random numbers where the sum of their squares is nearly
>   equal to 1.

Assuming nearly equal implies some small delta

```
delta = 0.00000000001
gene_value_1 = random.uniform(0,1)
gene_value_2 = math.sqrt(1.0 - gene_value_1**2)
gene_value_2 = random.uniform(gene_value_2-delta,gene_value_2+delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

`isclose` has a default tolerance of 10^-9; this may have been too tight for your purposes.  Since you failed to specify the problem, I'll try a version without using the function at all:

```
import random

tol = 0.01    # Tolerance: how close to 1.0 do we have to be?

# For illustration, try 1000 times; only a few will get close enough.
for _ in range(1000):
    gene_value_1 = random.uniform(0, 1)
    gene_value_2 = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if abs((gene_value_1**2 + gene_value_2**2) - 1.0) < tol:
        print(gene_value_1, gene_value_2)
```

Output:

```
0.494788483232363 0.8684265825591323
0.2534457849885592 0.9641226120957478
0.7203139196461331 0.6907040618050416
0.5209764827501758 0.8494629588837268
0.35131722626502326 0.9326863439646066
0.9090058297727053 0.41193607685541955
0.38668550268554913 0.9211652839586227
0.4981396919166827 0.8716609641505723
0.32335194126436084 0.9515174500031403
0.8975054159419422 0.4338981696304519
0.9055370877201422 0.4174842572890476
0.6174536739530609 0.789563981024344
0.8238168460048567 0.564248521210536
0.8086540730748032 0.5877591346132056
0.9483222364877975 0.3290608007951834
0.7610944343401178 0.6448728614809394
0.9909209668202087 0.1333222757510487
0.985161966125415 0.16537725793380365
0.39363133060821665 0.9232464739964449
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two values whose square sums to 1, the geometrically based suggestions already made are excellent, i.e., generate an angle θ uniformly over [0,2π) and use sine(θ) and cosine(θ).  However, if you want to extend to higher dimensions, this approach gets nasty pretty quickly.

A nice alternative that generalizes to arbitrary numbers of dimensions is to generate independent Gaussians and normalize them. N independent multivariate Gaussians can be represented as an N-dimensional vector that is equally likely to point in any direction in N-space.  Generate the vector, normalize its length to 1.0, and voila!, instant sum of squares == 1.  If you want the sum of squares to be near one but not equal, you can randomize the normalizing scale factor.

```
from functools import reduce
from math import sqrt
from random import gauss, uniform

def sum_of_squares_is_one(n = 2):
    if ((n < 2) or (int(n) != n)) is True:
        raise Exception("Invalid argument for n")
    l = [gauss(0.0, 1.0) for _ in range(n)]
    norm = sqrt(reduce(lambda sum,x: sum + x*x, l, 0.0)) # / uniform(0.95, 1.05)
    return [x / norm for x in l]

print(sum_of_squares_is_one())
# => [-0.5507487065788466, -0.8346711101995371]
print(sum_of_squares_is_one(5))
# => [-0.5985784458250389, 0.3741123562198886, -0.2600006068118713, -0.5415988718467569, 0.37525209604886034]
```

Pass an explicit argument for `n` to get an N-dimensional result.
Uncomment the division by the uniform if you want to get values whose sum of squares is in [0.95, 1.05], or adjust the range to your needs.